# Chrome unable to display base64 as iframe source

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, base64, src

Basically I have some HTML encoded as base64 with an iframe with said html set as the source.

```
<iframe src="data:html;base64, PGRpdiBzdHlsZT0iY29sb3I6cmVkOyI+VGhpcyB0ZXh0IGlzIHJlZC48L2Rpdj4="></iframe>
```

[jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/mTgna/)

The above code should display as:

```
This text is red.
```

Firefox seems to be able to display it with no issues, however Chrome attempts to download it as a file and not display it at all. IE also has issues, but I'm not too concerned regarding this particular project.

I'd like to know why this is happening, and the resolution if any.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by bad specification of the data type.

If you refer back to the original code, the specification was as follows;

```
data:html;base64,
```

However, the correct specification type for HTML is;

```
data:text/html;base64,
```

Firefox seemed to understand the malformed version, Chrome did not.